# Library not loaded: '@rpath/OneSignalCore.framework/OneSignalCore' - Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: xcode, react-native

Xcode Version: 14.2
Device: Iphone 6S
React Native Version: 0.69.6

When I try to upload my react native project to my ios device, I get this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I added "OneSignalCore.xcframework" to the library, then I pressed the run button. It gave an error again and said that it could not find "OneSignalOutcomes.xcframework". So I added it to the library and it worked as a result.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I got is really very weird and it just came out while trying and was able to resolve this issue for me. So if anyone here is getting the same error can try this.

**Steps**

**Open Xcode** -> **Select your app in the Targets** -> **Go to General Tab** -> **Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content.**

Click on **+** . Search for `OneSignal` in it and add OneSignal.xcframework.

Here comes the weird part.

After `OneSignal.xcframework` is added. Just remove this `OneSignal.xcframework` by selecting and clicking **-**.

Now just build your app again. Your app should run now.

!!! **IMPORTANT** !!!
If doesn't work try with `OneSignalCode`

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work.